# Every time I try to run my flutter app from a physical device I get this errror

Tags: flutter

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout of 120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file: /home/haggai/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.4-all/aadb4xli5jkdsnukm30eibyiu/gradle-7.4-all.zip
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:61)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From the given error, it seems that you're using Mac OS.

Solution:
Please Delete the .gradle folder located at  /home/haggai/.gradle
and run the flutter app again.